# Can I output String with expression language in custom tag?

Tags: jsp, servlets, jstl

I am trying to write a custom tag such that instead of writing

`<div>${message}</div>`

I want to replace it with

`<my:msg/>`

But I'm not sure how to evaluate EL inside custom tag

```
public class MyTag extends TagSupport { 
...
    @Override
    public int doStartTag() throws JspException {

        try {
            JspWriter out = pageContext.getOut();
            out.println("<div>${message}</div>");
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            throw new JspException("Error:" + ioe.getMessage());
        }
        return SKIP_BODY;
    }
...
}
```

this prints the literal string ${message}

Comment: Is there any constraint here such that you can't retrieve the value through the `PageContext` object? You should have direct access to this value if it associated with the request, for example.

Comment: I can retrieve PageContext object, but I was inspecting it while debugging but cant find how to evaluate an EL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [EL wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info) gives a good explanation of how expressions are evaluated through [`PageContext#findAttribute()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/jsp/JspContext.html#findAttribute%28java.lang.String%29) in the JavaBeans section of the article. The basic idea of the method is to search for the first non-null attribute in the page, request, session, or application scope matching the name of the argument.

In your example, the container will not evaluate the output of your tag file because your custom tag is evaluated by a separate handler as content is generated for the client. So the idea is that you should not output markup that needs additional evaluation once the tag handler is done with it.

**Your handler using PageContext#findAttribute()**

```
public class MyTag extends TagSupport { 
...
    @Override
    public int doStartTag() throws JspException {

        try {
            JspWriter out = pageContext.getOut();
            out.println(pageContext.findAttribute("message"));
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            throw new JspException("Error:" + ioe.getMessage());
        }
        return SKIP_BODY;
    }
...
}
```

Alternatively, if you know what scope the variable is guaranteed to exist, it might be clearer to retrieve it more directly.

**Direct Retrieval - Request Parameter**

```
public class MyTag extends TagSupport { 
...
    @Override
    public int doStartTag() throws JspException {

        try {
            JspWriter out = pageContext.getOut();
            out.println(pageContext.getRequest().getParameter("message"));
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            throw new JspException("Error:" + ioe.getMessage());
        }
        return SKIP_BODY;
    }
...
}
```